# Openshift - laravel uploaded files are removed after git push

Tags: laravel, openshift

I am testing my apps in OpenShift and I used the laravel framework. I created a folder named uploads in the public directory. I can upload images files in this public/upload folder. The problem is when I git push changes on my local computer to the remote files, all uploaded files are removed. I have searched about making a symbolic link in .openshift/action_hooks/deploy. I am using the code below but it seems it is not working to retain the uploaded files

```
echo ".............pre_build............creating symlinks................."
if [ ! -d "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/public/uploads" ]; then
    mkdir $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/public/uploads
    echo directory made.
fi
ln -sf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/public/uploads $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/public/uploads
echo ".................creating symlinks completed........................"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not scalable, you should use the `data` directory. https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html